# GNOME auto arrange 2 windows horizontally?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window

On Ubuntu 17.10, pressing <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> (or right) puts the current window on half of the screen vertically.  I'd like the ability to do this horizontally.  Is there a way to implement that?

I'd prefer editing a config file, but if that isn't possible, a GNOME extension would be fine.  I'd rather not add a new program to do this but I guess it depends...

Answer (score 0):

gTile should do the trick.

[image: gtile move to top]

Check out https://superuser.com/questions/1120700/how-to-snap-a-window-to-the-top-bottom-with-gnome

Here is the extension page: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/